# SailsJS - Override default controllers to add global rule or restriction

Tags: sails.js

Due our business model we had to set for every record in the model: an 
 attribute `ownerID` and a `groupID`. As always, people from the same team can see their mates records but not those from the other communities.

I have the user's `groupID` in a session variable for each call coming from the front-end given all possible requests have to be authenticated.

I've been thinking about that but I cannot find a nice place to set a piece of code to make Sails just return user's community records for every model.

An option is overriding all default methods for all controllers, but I think it's not necessary to override all `find`, `findOne`, etc methods to adding this simple restriction given it should be applied for ALL models. For sure there's a more elegant way of reaching this using hooks or any policy but I dont give with that.

My goal is if I `get /houses` just return the houses from the community of the authenticated user even if are all together in the database and apply this restriction for ALL models.

I hope you can understand...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sails-permissions provided this functionality but not sure if it is still being maintained or even available for sails v1*. I have a similar setup on a business application, created a policy filterByUserGroup, in the policy I do something like `let blueprint = req.options.action;` then if the action is find or findOne. I do something like `if(req.options.where) { req.options.where.group_id = req.session.user.groupId;} else { req.options.where = { group_id : req.session.user.groupId};}`. I then added that policy to routes where I needed it.

Comment: I had a look to sails-policies but could not solve my config given is designed to manage roles nor organization permissions. Also wanted to apply for ALL methods but with no luck. My solution was adding in a session variable the groupID and override find() in every controller adding the group check rule in where clause. Is not probably the best solution but is working like a charm.